# Adding a time to randomly generated list of dates

Tags: php, laravel, php-carbon

Down below I am trying to generate an array of dates that meet criteria of Sundays, Mondays, and Thursdays since the year 1990. With those dates, I want to add a time of 7 pm for every Event that is created. Is this possible with the Carbon package?

```
public function run()
{
    $start = Carbon::parse('First Monday of January 1990');
    $nextMonth = Carbon::now()->addMonth();

    collect([
        'monday' => false,
        'thursday' => false,
        'sunday' => true
    ])->flatMap(function ($bool, $day) use ($start, $nextMonth) {
        return $this->dates($start, $nextMonth, $day, $bool);
    })->sort(function ($a, $b) {
        return strtotime($a) - strtotime($b);
    })->values()->map(function ($date, $key) {
        return factory(Event::class)->create([
            'name' => 'Event '.($key + 1),
            'slug' => 'event'.($key + 1),
            'venue_id' => Venue::inRandomOrder()->first()->id,
            'date' => $date
        ]);
    })->filter(function ($event) {
        return $event->date->lte(Carbon::today()->addWeeks(2));
    });
}

protected function dates(Carbon $from, Carbon $to, $day, $last = false)
{
    $step = $from->copy()->startOfMonth();
    $modification = sprintf($last ? 'last %s of next month' : 'next %s', $day);

    $dates = [];
    while ($step->modify($modification)->lte($to)) {
        $dates[$step->timestamp] = $step->copy();
    }

    return $dates;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a time of 7 pm you can use Carbon setter method `$date->hour = 19`. See http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-setters

Comment: Would I apply that inside of the dates method or inside one of the collection methods I"m running in my run method of my seeder?

Comment: That depends on when you need it, but using it in the factory will save it to the DB.